# Google map api,how to handle marker hover event for all the markers at the same position(Overlapping markers)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map API with angular. In a simple application, on the left side there is a MAP with lots of markers and on the right side, there is a list of the table which contains information about the markers, one row for each marker. And on marker hover I am highlighting row for the hovered marker on right side with below code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
            var temp_marker_name = this.marker_name;
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.active_row_name = temp_marker_name;
            });
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.active_row_name = '';
            });
        });
```

So here, I set name on marker hover and based on the name, I highlight the row on right side.

Now, there is one case where more than one markers are plotted at the same position, and when I hover over that marker it highlights only one row on right side.

But I want to highlight all rows for the markers at that position.So, I want something that the hover event will fire for all the markers at the same position and I can make an array of names and then I can put a condition on that to highlight rows.

Answer (score 1):

The hover will only detect the marker on the top. What you may do is maintain an array of your markers  and in your event listeners iterate through this array to get markers which have the same lat lng value.

Edit:
Once you have the list of markers then for each of the markers at same location you can manually trigger the mouseover event.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover');
```

Comment: I want something which calls hover event for every markers on same position. In d3.js there is something like .on('mousemove.passThru') which calls for every Overlapping SVG Layers. I want something like that for markers.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You don't get that kind of event out of the box though.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the bottom marker visible by seeing its zIndex above the other marker's zIndex.

```
function createMarker(point, html, i, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    zIndex: 0,
    draggable: true

  });
  var activeIcon, idleIcon;

  idleIcon = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';

  marker.setIcon(idleIcon);

  var elem = document.getElementById('a' + i);
  if (!!elem) {
    elem.onmouseover = function() {
      marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png');
      marker.setZIndex(100);
    }
    elem.onmouseleave = function() {
      marker.setIcon(idleIcon);
      marker.setZIndex(0);
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

  });

  return marker;
}
```

proof of concept fiddle

```
var geocoder;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var name = "Event1";
  var address = "address 1";
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42, -72);
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  var image1 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
  var image2 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';

  var i = 0;
  createMarker(point, html, i, map);

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.02, -72.02);
  name = "Event2";
  address = "address 2";
  html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  i++;
  var marker = createMarker(point, html, i, map);

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.01, -72.01);
  name = "Event3";
  address = "address 3";
  html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  i++;
  var marker = createMarker(point, html, i, map);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.01, -72.01);
  name = "Event4";
  address = "address 3";
  html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  i++;
  var marker = createMarker(point, html, i, map);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());


}

function createMarker(point, html, i, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    zIndex: 0,
    draggable: true

  });
  var activeIcon, idleIcon;

  idleIcon = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';

  marker.setIcon(idleIcon);

  var elem = document.getElementById('a' + i);
  if (!!elem) {
    elem.onmouseover = function() {
      marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png');
      marker.setZIndex(100);
    }
    elem.onmouseleave = function() {
      marker.setIcon(idleIcon);
      marker.setZIndex(0);
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

  });

  return marker;
}


function hover(marker, i) {
  document.getElementById('a' + i).onmouseover = function() {
    marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png');
  }
  document.getElementById('a' + i).onmouseleave = function() {
    marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png');
  }
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="a0">Event 1 address 1</div>
<div id="a1">Event 2 address 2</div>
<div id="a2">Event 3 address 3</div>
<div id="a3">Event 4 address 3</div>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

more info [[Marker hovering on a Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118984/marker-hovering-on-a-google-map][1])